# How to integrate Unity project with Xamarin

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to integrate a AR based Unity project , which is then converted to an AAR package into Xamarin.Forms?

Or should we use Xamarin.Android (Native) for this ?

Comment: Unity itself can export mobile apps. Why do you need to use Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: @LexLi Our app also has parts which doesn't involve AR that's why we are planning on using Xamarin

Comment: Xamarin has its own engine, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/graphics-games/urhosharp/index and so far there is not yet any documentation on how to mix Unity and Xamarin.